# Deserialize incoming message in JSON format

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I am writing an application which gets a message in JSON format from a specific web service.
This is how JSON message looks like:

```
[
  15,
  "5667",
  {
    "status":"Uploaded",
    "uploadTime":"2023-07-05T11:03:19+00:00",
    "progress":12
  }
]
```

Also this is my class used during deserialization to .NET object:

```
public class WebServiceNotification
{
  public int typeId { get; set; }
  public string msgId { get; set; }
  public string status { get; set; }
  public string uploadTime{ get; set; }
  public int progress{ get; set; }
}
```

I tried both approach Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json, but without luck. And yes I know there is no field for value 15 and also for the value 5667.

Code for deserialization:

```
string msgFromWebService = "[15,"5667",{"status":"Uploaded","uploadTime":"2023-07-05T11:03:19+00:00","progress":12}]";

var ocppMsg1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WebServiceNotification>(msgFromWebService);
var ocppMsg2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebServiceNotification>(msgFromWebService);
```

Error message I get from JsonSerializer.Deserialize:

> Unhandled exception. System.Text.Json.JsonException: '1' is an invalid start of a property name. Expected a '"'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.

And the message from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject:

> Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: ,. Path '', line 1, position 3.

Question:

Can I deserialize JSON message with missing fields where only values are present?

In this case 15 and "5667".

Comment: The JSON string doesn't match the object. The string contains an array of mixed types , not a single object. This isn't a matter of missing fields, there are no fields in an array

Comment: If possible, change the format to something sensible. If not, you'll have to deserialize this into a JArray and then deserialize the third item into an object with `JObject.ToObject<SomeType>()`. The type should match the content

Comment: Will try this and get back with more info. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you need another class for those three properties and then the root class will have `[JsonExtensionData] public Dictionary<string, OtherClass> moreDetails {get;set;} = new();`

Comment: `from element in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<JToken>>(json) select element switch { JObject o => o.ToObject<WebServiceNotification>(), JValue v => (string)v };`